# Deploy Laravel backend with React-Create-App front end

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router

I have a Laravel backend with all API created in the `routes/api.php` so in my public folder I don't have anything I use.

I then have a react app made with [React Create App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) so it has its own code and a build folder with all the built files.

In a shared hosting space I have my public_html folder where I want to place them both. I don't know where to place what. So my question is only on the file position in the server, where to put Laravel and where to put the react app.

The routing is done by react but also Laravel has an `https://example.com/api/myurl` endpoint with its routing engine. I'm wondering how to get them working together. Is there a way?

Comment: You need to use both routes (frontend, backend) - Frontend (React) will communicate via API to Backend (Laravel) - you can as example create the https://example.com/ for frontend and https://example.com/core/api for backend.

Answer (score 0):

Your front end route will call the backend api to return data and the new page will be rendered on the front end with updated data.

So from example.com when you navigate away to example.com/route1, the navigation action should call the /route1 route from the routes/api.php.

/route1 will contain a controller with data you want to return.

Once the data is returned, you'll use react router to display the example.com/route1 page with the returned data and react components.

Hope this helps?

[image]

Comment: Thank you anche good. But I had to clarify my question because I need only to know the file positions, where do I put Laravel and where the react app.

Comment: If you are following the above design, react and api can be in 2 separate folders. 
React will be minified, whereas php you'll have composer